# URL needs trailing slash - openshift with nginx

Tags: nginx, openshift

I have node.js app with nginx deployed to openshift.

this is what my **apis.yaml** file looks like:

```
...
routes:
    - name: 'somename'
      paths:
        - 'somepath'
```

this is what my **nginx.conf** file looks like:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    
    root /www/data/;
    index index.html;
    access_log off;

    location / {
        gzip on;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Problem is when I try to access application.

I **can** access https://mydomain/somepath/ (see trailing slash)

I **can not** access https://mydomain/somepath (without trailing slash)

Does anybody know what am I missing?

## EDIT

I can access also https://mydomain/somepath but not static files. With trailing slash i can access also them (vue.js, css files, images)

Comment: try - `location = /`

Comment: it says unknown directive "<<<<<<<<" on line below location = / {